# Saving result of a Query in a variable

Tags: python, pymysql

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='......', user='....', password='.....', database='......')
cursor=connection.cursor()
q1="select count(*) from lk_employee_data where date(entry_time)=('2020-11-18')"
cursor.execute(q1)
```

q1 query is giving result 1.While if i run same query in Database result is 190.So what I want to know why it is not working correctly.And I also want to save result of q1 query in a variabe.

Comment: `cursor.execute(q1).fetchall()`

Answer (score 0):

cursor.execute() will return the number of affected rows by the query executed. To retrieve data you have to access to cursor results directly as below:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
q1="select count(*) from lk_employee_data where date(entry_time)=('2020-11-18')"
cursor.execute(q1)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: giving error:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Comment: @NipunTulsyan I have updated the answer now. This should work as expected